# where to code for ajax to send data to server to save action of button click in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, datatable

I am new to using datatable plugin for ajax loaded  table, i want to update a column of multiple rows in database for this action button is used.
here is current code for button click

```
// handle group actionsubmit button click
grid2.getTableWrapper().on('click', '.table-group-action-submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var action = $(".table-group-action-input", grid2.getTableWrapper());
    if (action.val() != "" && grid2.getSelectedRowsCount() > 0) {
        grid2.setAjaxParam("customActionType", "group_action");
        grid2.setAjaxParam("customActionName", action.val());
        grid2.setAjaxParam("id", grid2.getSelectedRows());
        grid2.getDataTable().fnDraw();
        grid2.clearAjaxParams();
    } else if (action.val() == "") {
        Metronic.alert({
            type: 'danger',
            icon: 'warning',
            message: 'Please select an action',
            container: grid2.getTableWrapper(),
            place: 'prepend'
        });
    } else if (grid2.getSelectedRowsCount() === 0) {
        Metronic.alert({
            type: 'danger',
            icon: 'warning',
            message: 'No record selected',
            container: grid2.getTableWrapper(),
            place: 'prepend'
        });
    }
});
```

where to code ajax to send data set by grid2.setAjaxParam

any help much appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes to the same url from where datatable fetching data:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["customActionType"]) &&
 $_REQUEST["customActionType"] == "group_action") {
    $records["customActionStatus"] = "OK"; 
    $records["customActionMessage"] = "Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!";
  }
```

in case anyone else need this,